# Google Visualization API - Org Chart Layout

Tags: google-visualization, orgchart

Using the [Org Chart](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/orgchart.html#Loading) in the Google Visualization API, is there a way to flip the chart to a vertical layout instead of horizontal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately no. It is not possible at the moment.

This feature has been requested in [Issue #47](http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=47) on the Google Visualization API issue tracker.

You may want to star the issue to let Google know about  your interest in this feature.

Answer (score 1):

GetOrgChart jQuery widget has oeriantation option to show vertical org chart

Orientation of the GetOrgChart widget.

- getOrgChart.RO_TOP
- getOrgChart.RO_BOTTOM
- getOrgChart.RO_RIGHT
- getOrgChart.RO_LEFT

Default value: getOrgChart.RO_TOP

Code examples:

```
$("#people").getOrgChart({          
    orientation: getOrgChart.RO_LEFT,
    dataSource: [
        { id: 1, parentId: null, Name: "Amber McKenzie"},
        { id: 2, parentId: 1, Name: "Ava Field"},
        { id: 3, parentId: 1, Name: "Evie Johnson"}]
});
```

[JSFIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GetOrgChart/j6GBq/)